# Java - Generic Number method signature bound to specific subclasses

Tags: java, generics, enums

I would like to write a method which takes a generic `Number` as an argument and returns another `Number`, whose type may possibly differ from the first and is passed as a second argument. Something like this:

```
public <N1 extends Number, N2 extends Number> N2 op(N1 num, Class<N2> retType) {
    //Sample operation, where type conflicts arise.
    return retType.cast(num + 3);
}
```

Of course, I can't just cast `N1` to `N2` if they are, say, `Integer` and `Long`. However, `Number` offers `doubleValue()`, `intValue()`, ... , methods that could allow me to partially work around the issue with a switch/case statement. That would restrict me to the return types of the `xxxValue()` methods the `Number` class exposes, thus cutting off `AtomicInteger`, `AtomicLong`, `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal`.

This is still acceptable for the application I have in mind, but my methods would not be able to properly handle any custom or future official extensions of the `Number` class if not with a `default` statement in the switch/case block which should arbitrarily decide which `xxxValue()` method to invoke, or throw an exception (which I would like to avoid). I could use an enumeration to encapsulate parameters by type, but I am afraid my code would get too convoluted and tricky to use.

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819824/java-generic-type-number) gives further insight as to declaring a single generic type for two parameters (it doesn't enforce that both parameters will be, in fact, of the same type at runtime), which sure is worth mentioning here.

What I want to achieve is:

- Declare a method with some *generic* (in a broad sense) `Number` parameters, possibly more methods with a different number of parameters (e.g. a method with two, a method with three parameters) but still generic in each of them.
- The parameters must be restricted to some well-known extensions of `Number` (e.g. `Integer`, `Double`).
- The parameters may come in multiple combinations, potentially any of `(Double, Integer)`, `(Double, Double)`, `(Integer, Double)`, `(Integer, Integer)`.

I would like not to define multiple methods with different signatures. Even while fixing the return type e.g. to `Double`, the number of methods would explode as more arguments and types are added.

Of course, I may always resort to specific, ad-hoc implementations for each method, as I am probably not going to need every possible combination of types. I would still like my design to be flexible enough while enforcing these type constraints.

Comment: "The parameters must be restricted to some well-known extensions of Number" - that would be a union type, which Java doesn't have. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697562/is-there-a-union-in-java-generics and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48993454/parameterize-a-class-with-one-of-a-fixed-set-of-types for some ideas, but I don't think any of them will work for a method like this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my best workaround, which calls the constructor that accepts a String as the parameter, and returns a null if it fails (Edited to remove printStackTrace and remove one unnecessary branch)

```
public static <R extends Number> R op(Number num, Class<R> retType) {
    BigDecimal three = BigDecimal.valueOf(3);
    BigDecimal bdNum = new BigDecimal(num.toString());

    //add three
    BigDecimal bdResult = bdNum.add(three);

    String strResult = bdResult.toString();
    Constructor[] cons = retType.getDeclaredConstructors();
    for (Constructor con: cons) {
        if (con.getParameterCount() == 1) {
            if (con.getGenericParameterTypes()[0] == String.class) {
                try {
                    return (R)con.newInstance(strResult);
                } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | NumberFormatException e) {
                } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                    //if here then either the decimal place is causing a problem
                    // when converting to integral type,
                    // or the value is too large for the target type

                    // so let's try to remove the decimal point by truncating it.
                    strResult = bdResult.toBigInteger().toString();
                    try {
                        return (R)con.newInstance(strResult);
                    } catch (NumberFormatException | IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException | InvocationTargetException e1) {
                    }
                }
                //if here, then the most likely the integral type is too large
                //like trying to put 3,000,000,000 into an int
                // when largest int possible is 2,147,483,647
            }
            //if here, then no constructors with 1 String parameter
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work on AtomicInteger, AtomicLong, but works on all other number types

Comment: It feels a little too heavy-duty for the use I have in mind, I am afraid. Since in fact I don't need BigInteger and BigDecimal, I think I may resort to interfaces requiring and returning the same type of argument, like `double op(double par1, double par2) {...}`, after all it's just four methods for float, double, int and long. I think it may be a fair compromise with a template pattern maybe...